# Is it possible to have a consistent NavBar and Footer in a Xamarin application that uses native views?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin forms application, in which I would like to have a consistent header and footer (Like below in white) for every view in the application. The header would be a nav bar and the footer would also have a button on it.

I also want this to only be implemented once instead of having the same code reused for every view.

[image]

The Xamarin application has one view in which it's implementation is native platform-specific (It has an activity in The .Android project and a storyboard in the .iOS project). This implementation is accessed using an interface which is implemented in the two projects to create the view. This means I can't use anything like a `ControlTemplate`, as they cannot be accessed by platform specific views.

With this in mind, How can I implement the header and footer so it shows up each `ContentPage` instance and every native view with only the one implementation?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a base page that all of your pages inherit from, and implement the common UI in the page page.  Then your native views could be implemented as ContentViews within a page using Custom Renderers

Comment: @Jason at the moment the native views are created by implementing an interface method inside each project to either start the activity or storyboard. How would I be able to implement the steps you suggested so the activity/storyboard files are part of the content view inside a page when they are currently detached from the Xamarin.forms project?

Comment: @Jc781 Welcome to SO! Hi, Jason means using [Xamarin.Forms ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview) to show native view by using [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I understood that, but I can't find any documentation online about how to put my existing .axml and storyboard files that are opened by an interface into a content page? They are completely separate views so how can I put them into a content page? Do you have any tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: @Jc781 Sorry, it seems to be impossible to put them in content page. Even using ContentView , because their renderer are inherited from UIView or View, not a UIViewController or Activity. Therefore, this should be impossible to achieve this in Xamarin Forms application.